# How to check if a class has specific function to avoid compile time issues?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors

I have two class A and B, with a common function doing some operation on both of them with just a minor difference.

I tried using `std::is_same`, but looks like it won't prevent compile-time issues.

```
class A {
public: 
    void aSpecificFunctionToA() {
    }
};

class B {
};


template<typename T>
void someFunction(T obj) {
    if(std::is_same<T, A>::value)
    {
        obj.aSpecificFunctionToA();
    }
}
```

How to tackle this situation?

Comment: You need a [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if)

Comment: That said, this is usually bad design. Consider using *function overloading* for type-specific things instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you explicit why it's a bad design ? Because it's not part of the API and it may surprise the user.

Comment: the functions I am using have long code,
the variation is only for 1 specific function.

writing the entire code again would be a bad design I guess as the code will be redundant. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude constexpr if won't work, I am using c++11

Comment: @MartinMorterol Explicit selection on type (as in the question) could very quickly become hairy, hard to read and understand, and therefore also hard to maintain. Using the type-selection of the language itself (overloading) makes the code clearer, cleaner, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use c++17, then you can use `if constexpr` to conditionally compile code if it satisfies some constraints.

```
template<typename T>
void someFunction(T obj) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, A>::value)
    {
        obj.aSpecificFunctionToA();
    }
    // ... code for all Ts
}
```

---

Before c++17, you can use an overload for `A`, and put the code that is common to all `T`s into a separate function:

```
template<typename T>
void common_code(T obj) {
  // ... code for all Ts
}

template<typename T>
void someFunction(T obj) {
  common_code(obj);
}

void someFunction(A obj) {
  obj.aSpecificFunctionToA();
  common_code(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one class having `aSpecificFunctionToA` (well, in this case the name is poorly choose) you can use SFINAE.

Full C++11 :

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail_traits
{
template <class...>
struct Args
{
};

template <class... T>
using void_t = void;

template <class T, class args, class = void>
struct has_aSpecificFunctionToA : std::false_type
{
};
template <class T, class... args>
struct has_aSpecificFunctionToA<
    T,
    Args<args...>,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().aSpecificFunctionToA(std::declval<args>()...))>> : std::true_type
{
};

} // namespace detail_traits
template <class T, class... Args>
using has_aSpecificFunctionToA = typename detail_traits::has_aSpecificFunctionToA<T, detail_traits::Args<Args...>>;


class A
{
  public:
    void aSpecificFunctionToA() {
    std::cout << "aSpecificFunctionToA" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_aSpecificFunctionToA<T>::value>::type someFunction(T obj)
{
        obj.aSpecificFunctionToA();
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!has_aSpecificFunctionToA<T>::value>::type someFunction(T )
{
        std::cout << "some code for class without aSpecificFunctionToA" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_aSpecificFunctionToA<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_aSpecificFunctionToA<B>::value << std::endl;

    someFunction(A{});
    someFunction(B{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer simple old fashion solution:

```cpp
#define LOG std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

class A {
public: 
    void aSpecificFunctionToA() {
        LOG;
    }
};

class B {
};


template<typename T>
void someFunction(T obj) {
    LOG;
}

void someFunction(A obj) {
    LOG;
    obj.aSpecificFunctionToA();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/brPGr6

Answer (score -1):

This code prevented the compiler to build that particular if block based on a const bool expression.

```
const bool flag = std::is_same<T, A>::value;
#if(flag)
{
    obj.aSpecificFunctionToA();
}
#endif
```

Comment: Preprocessor directives (like `#if`) is handled *before* the code is actually compiled. That means the preprocessor doesn't know anything about variables, and least of all their values (even if they are compile-time constants).